# How to create a logo for an Android Studio project?

Tags: android, gradle

I would like to create a logo for my Android Studio project. I know it is possible, however, I couldn't find out how to do it, please let me know, thank you. I don't mean setting logo for my app (launcher icon etc), but for the Android project.

My desired effect would be the same as shown in the screenshot (with the blue logo).[image]

Comment: like android Studio logo? 
use Adobe CS or any other tool or use online logo maker sites

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio maybe this might help

Comment: I meant the logo on the left. I'll post a new screenshot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on the project. The context menu gives you an option to set the icon.

[image]